# What is the market share for the various .Net framework versions?

Tags: .net

Does anyone know if these stats are collected or exist anywhere? Any anecdotal evidence is at least slightly helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe a [search popularity](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=.net%201.1,.net%202.0,.net%203.0,.net%203.5,.net%204) will give you a new view.

Answer (score 6):

I found this link: http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?biz.5.592012
Somewhere in the body you'll find the following figures:

> ```
> ~80% .Net 1+
> ~50% .Net 2+
> ~20% .Net 3+ (~17%  Vista)
> ~03% .Net 3.5+ (Skewed b/c I have 3.5...)
> ```

I don't know where these numbers come from, but it does make some sense. HP and ATI have their software written in .NET (1.1 I believe), so almost everyone who has an HP printer or ATI graphics card has .NET 1.1 . All Vista users have .NET 3.0 .

Answer (score 2):

We have some statistics [here](http://www.nemo-docs.com/blog/usage-statistics/) based on usage statistics from our WPF program. It might be a bit scewed because our installer recommends, but doesn't force, people to install .NET 4.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote software that runs on .Net 2.0 but as part of the telemetry it reports back the installed versions so I can determine when I can upgrade without disrupting too many existing customers. While I could extract the info on all installed versions, I currently do a monthly summary of the highest installed version since that's what I'll use to determine when to upgrade. This is what it looked like for April 2015.

- 2.0 - 0.79%
- 3.0 - 0.52%
- 3.5 - 15.22%
- 4.0 - 31.50%
- 4.5 - 51.97%

You can extrapolate the 2.0 and 3.0 numbers from 3.5 since 3.5 requires/includes those earlier versions to be installed. Likewise 4.5 replaces 4.0 with full backward compatibility so 83.47% of our existing customer base is compatible with 4.0.

As a bonus here's the information on the OS distribution for our customer base for that particular application.

- Windows XP - 23.12%
- Windows Vista - 1.04%
- Windows 7 - 66.75%
- Windows 8 - 8.83%

This is the data for active installations, I filter out installations that have not had any data reported for months.

Comment: Hi @Steve , i have been looking all over for such information, i need a little more help from you.
could you tell
1. what percent of windows 7 users have 4.5 installed
2. what is the total number of users are we taking about here
3. what is your target audience and majority users are from which country?
this would be a great help thnx

Comment: 71.6% of our Windows 7 customers have .Net 4.5 installed. This isn't widely distributed so the sample size of active installations is small, between 300 and 400 right now. Target audience is small businesses and K-12 schools but our customer base includes some federal and municipal government offices too. Probably 98-99% of our customers are in the US.

Answer (score 0):

Might be interesting to add some Linux / Mac figures into the mix?

I know [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) comes with [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) installed by default from at least 8.04