# Availability statistics of .NET versions on various Windows versions

Tags: .net, windows

I'm looking for some research or statistics on the availability of various .NET Framework versions on specific Windows versions. For example, Windows 7 shipped with .NET Framework version 3.5, but "almost all" Windows 7 PCs "in the wild" have been upgraded to at least version 4.0 (either via Windows Update, another application's install bundle, or manually). I want to replace "almost all" with rough figures, and to do the same for other Framework/OS combinations, like .NET 4.5 on Windows 8+.

I know this is somewhat subjective, since it's impossible to survey *all* PCs in the wild; but hopefully there is some research out there. Even gross statistics might be very useful.

The type of information provided by http://caniuse.com/ for Web technology availability, which takes into account browser market share percentages, would be ideal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the market share for the various .Net framework versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933755/what-is-the-market-share-for-the-various-net-framework-versions)